# Converting two single dimensional arrays(each one made up with an arraylist) to a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I wanted to know if it is possible to convert two single dimensional array into one two dimensional array using arraylists.

Here's my code:

```
String[] user = (String[])compList.toArray(new String[usersList.size()]);

String[] computer = (String[])compList.toArray(new String[compList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume

```
String[] user = (String[])compList.toArray(new String[usersList.size()]);
```

should be

```
String[] user = (String[])usersList.toArray(new String[usersList.size()]);
```

I don't think this is possible, assuming you want something like

```
String comuterUser[][]
```

where `computerUser[0]` is the user and `computerUser[1]` is the computer.  You'll have to iterate through the lists and populate the array. Something like (assuming the two lists are of equal length):

```
String computerUser[][] = new String[usersList.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < computerUser.lenth; i++) {
    computerUser[i] = new String[]{ usersList.get(i), compList.get(i) };
}
```

Best to have the two lists `ArrayList`s for speedy lookup.  I haven't tested the above, but it should work.

Comment: i tried the code but when i ran it i got this error: [[Ljava.lang.String;@53343ed0

Comment: I missed a square bracket pair in the array declaration.  Fixed in the code above.  Sorry, I tested it, it works now. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the arrays using System.arrayCopy.

```
private String[][] wideArray(String[] zero, String[] one) {
    String[][] combined=new String[2][Math.max(zero.length, one.length)];
    System.arraycopy(zero, 0, combined[0], 0, zero.length);
    System.arraycopy(one, 0, combined[1], 0, one.length);
    return combined;
}
```